Can Bash case-insensitive matching for executables in $PATH be disabled?
Today I typed Grep by mistake in my Terminal and to my surprise, the /bin/grep command was executed anyway. I do NOT want this behavior. But, it seems it's not possible to disable it. I'm currently using macOS 14.5.
I tested this with the builtin Bash 3.2.57 as well as Bash 5.2.26 from Homebrew, the results were the same.
$ Grep
usage: Grep [-abcdDEFGHhIiJLlMmnOopqRSsUVvwXxZz] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

$ echo $BASH
/bin/bash

$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.57(1)-release

$ command -v grep
/usr/bin/grep

$ command -v Grep
/usr/bin/Grep

$ stat -f%i /usr/bin/grep  # outputs inode
1152921500312525090

$ stat -f%i /usr/bin/Grep
1152921500312525090        # same

I was hoping to find a directive I could put in my .bash_profile, a shopt command for example. But these are the only two I could find, and I experimented with both of them without success.
$ shopt | grep case
nocaseglob      off
nocasematch     off


I’m interested to learn if this is possible. My hunch is you’d need a case sensitive file system to pull this off, though. For sure investigate .inputrc.

echo "set completion-ignore-case Off" >> ~/.inputrc disables the case-insensitive tab completion, but GREP still calls grep.

No it cannot!
If you check it with ls -ldi /usr/bin/grep /usr/bin/Grep you will
see that both exist on your filesystem but they are the same inode. Funny detail is that in fact the filesystem stores a case sensitive string, only one of the 16 combinations of  GREP writing ( trick to see it: cd /usr/bin ; echo [gG][rR][eE][pP] ). Some people talk of case preserving FS but it's just a way to increase confusion.
This is not a bash typical problem. Any shell will show you the same truth.
This is a filesystem "feature"¹.
This type of floating naming of files leads to source codes which can
create a file named "A" and later on open it as "a", thus creating bugs, vulnerabilities and crapwares.
The way to get rid of this problem, is:

make a complete backup copy of the
root filesystem on an external disk formatted as a "case-sensitive" one.
An excellent tool for this task is Carbon Copy Cloner ( you can achieve
the same perfect copy with rsync but with an arm long list of
arguments ).
Reboot on this external backup.
Reformat the original root filesystem as a "case-sensitive" one.
Make the symmetric copy from your external disk toward your original one.

( Tested and applied on many versions of macOS since > 20 years ).

¹)  Brief history of filesystems: case insensitive filesystems
    were created to help people who might experience problems
    with the use of uppercase.
    Since more than ½ century all Unix OS are running on
    case sensitive filesystems.
    Nowadays, most filesystems are even more open to the use of
    numerous alphabets, with many more differences than just
    lower case versus upper case and implement correctly UTF-8
    ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 ).


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

kshu+m has the globcasedetect option...
globcasedetect
  When this option is turned on, globbing (see Pathname Expansion above) and file name
  listing and completion (see In-line Editing Options above) automatically become case-
  insensitive on file systems where the difference between upper- and lowercase is ignored
  for file names. This is transparently determined for each directory, so a path pattern
  that spans multiple file systems can be part case-sensitive and part case-insensitive.
  In more precise terms, each slash-separated path name component pattern p is treated as
  ~(i:p) if its parent directory exists on a case-insensitive file system.  This option is
  only present on operating systems that support case-insensitive file systems.

That doesn't help with just typing GREP, but it does fix tab-completion.

I do not know of any directive. However, case sensitivity can be achieved by placing symbolic links in a case sensitive APFS volume. This case sensitive APFS volume would be added to the same APFS container where macOS is installed on case insensitive APFS volumes. These symbolic links would be to the commands found in the directories listed in the PATH variable. I realize this involves a large number of symbolic links, but these can be created quickly and easily by using script included in this answer. I was able to do this for macOS Monterey and the resulting case sensitive APFS volume size was under 1 MB.

This answer demonstrates one possible solution, However, most likely this solution would cause some unforeseen side effect. Such side effects may be minimized by only changing the PATH to include /Volumes/CS when you are manually entering commands.

Below are the steps needed to get case sensitive commands.

Use the Disk Utility to add a case sensitive APFS volume. Here I used the name CS.

Create the script file named myscript. The contents are given below.
#!/bin/zsh
main() {
    local f "scptname=$1" "volname=${2:-CS}"
    shift
    cd /
    if [[ UID -ne 0 ]]; then
        # Quit if you are not the root user.
        echo "$scptname: Not root user. Try using \"/usr/bin/sudo"\". >&2 
        return 1
    elif [[ ! -e "/Volumes/$volname" ]]; then
        # Quit if the volume does not exist.
        echo "$scptname: The volume does not exist: /Volumes/$volname" >&2 
        return 1
    fi
    # Remove the directories in the root of the volume
    # that are flagged as hidden.
    /usr/bin/find "/Volumes/$volname" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -flags hidden -exec /bin/rm -rf "{}" \;
    # Loop through all paths given in the PATH variable.
    IFS=: read -A <<<"${PATH//\/Volumes\/$volname/}"
    for f in "${reply[@]}"; do
        IFS="/" read -A <<<"$f"
        if [[ -n ${reply[1]:-} || -z ${reply[2]:-} ]]; then
            # Skip a path that does not start with / and or is the root.
            echo "$scptname: Skipping path: $f" >&2
        else
            if [[ -e "/Volumes/$volname$f" ]]; then
                # Skip if the path already occurred in PATH.
                echo "$scptname: The directory already exists: /Volumes/$volname$f" >&2
            else
                # Make the directory, flag hidden in root of volume and
                # create the symbolic links.
                /bin/mkdir -p "/Volumes/$volname$f"
                /usr/bin/chflags hidden "/Volumes/$volname/$reply[2]" >&2
                /usr/bin/find "$f" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 \( -type f -or -type l \) -exec /bin/ln -s "{}" "/Volumes/$volname{}" \;
            fi
        fi
    done
}
main "$(/usr/bin/basename "$0")" "$@"


Execute the script to create the symbolic links on the volume labeled CS. The directories created at the root of the CS volume are flagged as hidden and therefore will not show up in a Finder application window.
sudo ./myscript CS


Add /Volumes/CS to the PATH variable. Below is a sample of the contents a PATH variable.
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

After adding /Volumes/CS, this would change to the following.
/Volumes/CS/usr/local/bin:/Volumes/CS/usr/bin:/Volumes/CS/bin:/Volumes/CS/usr/sbin:/Volumes/CS/sbin


Note: You might need to enter hash -r after changing the PATH variable.



